# Image in tooltip

Tags: c#, image, tooltip

How do I include an image inside a tooltip?

The [MSDN documentation says it's possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754034%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I don't understand how.

(To clarify, I am *not* trying to show a text tooltip when hovering over an image.)
(I am not using Windows Presentation Foundation, I'm using (Edit) Winform.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you're not using WPF, but WinForms. Both can be used *by* C# programs (and in fact, any CLR programs, so that includes C#, VB.NET, C++/CLR, and so many more languages).

In WinForms I don't think that's supported, so you might have to be creative and do it yourself.

WPF does support it on the other hand.

P.S. The documentation you linked is for WPF. The how-to is indeed in the link you offered.
P.P.S imo you *should* use WPF (like, always. Unless you simply can't) - that's actually my answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake: I corrected my post. And thank you for answering my question. I will proceed accordingly.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I'm glad that you have, because I've been meaning to also say that WPF is really superior to WinForms in every way (I consider WinForms a still-supported legacy) so I'm sure you'll find it worthy to take the time to learn/use it. I think it's safe to say that WPF is the best GUI platform ever made.